# Hi, how can I subscribe the node(topic cmd_vel) of turtlesim to the node of my model?

Tags: gazebo, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have build a model in gazebo ROS which is moving through teleop keyboard. I want to subscribe cmd_vel of turtlesim to my model and move turtlesim along with my model. Do you have any idea how can I subscribe the node of turtlesim to the node of my model?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248906/hi,-how-can-i-subscribe-the-node(topic-cmd_vel)-of-turtlesim-to-the-node-of-my-model?/) by [manju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27548/manju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#### via command line:

You can remap topics with `/old_topic:=/new_topic`.  In your case:

`rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node /turtle1/cmd_vel:=/my_gazebo_robot/cmd_vel`

#### via launch file:

Within the node, you can use the remap tag.

```
<node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim">
  <remap from="/turtle1/cmd_vel" to="/my_gazebo_robot/cmd_vel" />
</node>
```

You can check if either method worked with `rostopic list` and `rostopic info /my_gazebo_robot/cmd_vel`. Note that `/my_gazebo_robot` might be several directories deep (such as if you have a base controller).

---

Originally posted by [petern3](https://answers.ros.org/users/28607/petern3/) with karma: 186 on 2016-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27548/manju/) on 2016-11-27**:
Hey, Thank you very much for the help. Its working!!